# Dojo Nested BorderContainer

Tags: dojo

This works:

```
<div dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" ... > Content, yada, yada, yada </div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<div>
  <div dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" ... > Content, yada, yada, yada </div>
</div>
```

By "doesn't work" I mean that the div does not display. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? BTW, placing the BorderContainer inside another div is the only change made between working and not working.

Comment: Can you update your post to include the complete BorderContainer declaration?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a border container to display it needs to have width and height applied via CSS. My guess is that your css rules are only being applied in the first instance and not the second instance, but without more detail on your surrounding page that's just a guess

Answer (score 0):

I did have a full height and width declared for the BorderContainer. I'm sure that this was something I was doing and not a problem with Dojo, it's just and nothing I did would make it work. I ran out of time so the answer to the problem was JQuery.

Steve G.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the dimensions on the outer div. This works:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <div dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" ... > Content, yada, yada, yada </div>
</div>
```